# sort vector of Coordinates(x,y,z) by vector of z value

Tags: c++

I have a vector of 3D coordinates:

```
vector<float64>contourdata;
contourdata={x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,...}
```

And I want to sort them by the vector of the z value.
How can I do it in c++?

Comment: make it a vector of a struct for a 3d vector then use std::sort with a compare function on the z value of your 3d vector.

Comment: I recommend that you first create a "point3d" structure to hold the individual `x`, `y` and `z` values. Then store copies of this structure in the vector. Then use `std::sort` with a suitable ordering function to use the `z` member of the structure.

Comment: Do you mean that I should make a matrix with 3 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <format>

// 3d points have 3 coordinates and
// we need to move those 3 values together when sorting
// It is also good to use "concepts" from real world as
// names in code : so define a struct representing a 3d coordinate.
// (Or use a 3d coordinate type from an existing library)
struct vec_3d_t
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

// helper function for outputing the values of one 3d point
// not essential for your problem.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vec_3d_t& data_point)
{
    os << std::format("({0},{1},{2})", data_point.x, data_point.y, data_point.z);
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    // std::vector is a (resizable) array
    // in this case to hold 3d coordinates
    // then initialize the data with some values
    // (you will probably get them from somewhere else, e.g. a file)
    std::vector<vec_3d_t> contour_data
    {
        {3.0,4.0,5.0},  // first coordinate
        {1.0,2.0,3.0},  // second etc ...
        {7.0,8.0,9.0}
    };

    // this calls the sort algorithm
    // using a function to compare two 3d points
    // to sort on z only compare z.
    std::sort(contour_data.begin(), contour_data.end(), [](const vec_3d_t& lhs, const vec_3d_t& rhs)
        {
            return lhs.z < rhs.z;
        });

    // range based for loop over data points
    for (const auto& data_point : contour_data)
    {
        std::cout << data_point << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Thanks!

Comment: @mahsa which parts don't you understand?

Comment: All of the building blocks I used are fairly standard C++. 
[vector](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdvector/),
[io-operators](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/overloading-the-io-operators/), [algorithms/sort](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-standard-library-algorithms/), [lambda functions](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-lambdas-anonymous-functions/), [range-based-for](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/for-each-loops/). Anyway I added some more comments to my code

Answer (score 2):

I struggled to find a way to use `std::sort` but you can always drop back the the C `qsort` stdlib function:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int compare(const double *A, const double *B) {
    return (A[2] <= B[2]) ? -1 : +1;
}

...

const size_t N = contourdata.size() / 3;
qsort(contourdata.data(), N, 3*sizeof(double),
      (int (*)(const void *, const void*))compare);
```

`qsort` (and `mergesort`  and `heapsort`) are sort
routines provided by the C standard library that have been around a long time. They are designed to sort data stored in contiguous arrays, but it is the programmers job to specify how the data is laid out and how to order the elements. `qsort` is not type-safe and generally not preferred, but can handle cases like this one. `qsort` has three parameters:

1. *A ptr to the base of the array.* Note that the ptr type is `void *` and thus the compiler has no clue about the type of data in the buffer. `std::vector` provides a `data()` method that provides a ptr to its internal buffer (which is guaranteed to be contiguous).
2. *The number of elements.* Since each element consists of 3 `double`'s we use we use the size of the `vector` divided by 3.
3. *The size of each element in bytes*.
4. *A ptr to a function used for comparing two elements*.  The arguments to each element are generic ptrs, but since we know they are ptrs to buffers containing `double`s we can specify the type in our `compare` function. Each element is an array of 3 doubles and, since we are using the z-component as the sort key, we compare the `double`s at offset 2. We return -1 for "less than" and +1 for "greater" -- this is enough to know how to sort.

Note that when passing the `compare` function to `qsort` we cast
it to the function ptr type that it expects to keep the
compiler from issuing a warning.

[image]

Comment: Please explain your code. Thanks!

Comment: The C stdlib `qsort()` (and `mergesort()`) functions sort contiguous arrays of data. I specify the number of elements `N` and the size in bytes of each element matching  how your data is layed out. I pass it a ptr to a `compare` function that returns an integer who sign specifies the order.  The `compare` function assumes `A` and `B` are ptrs to arrays of three doubles and  uses the z-component  for comparison.  I pass it a ptr to the underlying raw buffer in the `vector` via the `data()` method -- it sorts the underlying data as you specified.

Comment: I added a bunch of details to my answer. I hope it makes sense. `qsort` is very low level and is not type-safe -- use w care.